# I want to know solution fot show data correct

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

problem about sql command for show and sum data from data in database

have question from sql command
I want to show year , sum of income, and sum of outcome
example.
if i set year = 2022 and data from table `Receipt_Main_Code = '01'` is 500 and `Receipt_Main_Code = '05'` is null
it show

| 01 | 05 |
| --- | --- |
| 500 | null |

and I try to switch from 01 to 05 and 05 to 01 i  in sql command it show

| 05 | 01 |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |

```
select 
case when aa.year is null or aa.year = '' then '0000' else aa.year end as year
, case when aa.total_1 is null or aa.total_1 = '' then '0' else aa.total_1 end as total_1
, case when bb.total_2 is null or bb.total_2 = '' then '0' else bb.total_2 end as total_2
from (
        select year , sum(total_1) total_1 from 
        (
            SELECT substr(a.Payment_Date,1,4) year,a.Payment_Number  
            ,SUM(distinct b.Levied_Amount) total_1
            FROM receipt a join print_receipt b 
            where a.Receipt_Reference_Number  = b.Receipt_Reference_Number and b.Receipt_Main_Code = '01'
            and b.Receipt_Reference_Number  = '0000'
            group by substr(a.Payment_Date,1,4),a.Payment_Number 
        ) a 
    ) aa  
    left join (
        select year , sum(total_2) total_2 from 
        (
            SELECT substr(a.Payment_Date,1,4) year,a.Payment_Number  
            ,SUM(distinct b.Levied_Amount) total_2
            FROM receipt a join print_receipt b 
            where a.Receipt_Reference_Number  = b.Receipt_Reference_Number and b.Receipt_Main_Code = '05'
            and b.Receipt_Reference_Number  = '65111570001935012022111509001100000156'
            group by substr(a.Payment_Date,1,4),a.Payment_Number 
        ) b 
    ) bb on aa.year = bb.year
```